# What does the word qit'ran mean in Quran 18:96?

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation

[image]

The Yusuf Ali translation says it means "molten lead", whereas the Muhammed Pickthall translation says it means "molten copper".  Which is the correct meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Molten copper is the interpretation given by most exegetes, although molten iron and molten lead also exist.

> والقطر عند أكثر المفسرين النحاس المذاب ، وأصله من القطر ; لأنه إذا أذيب قطر كما يقطر الماء وقالت فرقة : القطر الحديد المذاب . وقالت فرقة منهم ابن الأنباري : الرصاص المذاب . وهو مشتق من قطر يقطر قطرا . ومنه وأسلنا له عين القطر
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura18-aya96.html#qortobi)</sup>